# can VPA and HPA(Auto Scaling) in kubernetes used together?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, autoscaling, kubernetes-pod, horizontal-scaling

**can the following be done : **

VPA relies on a number of different
measurements and is different from the HPA. We can
therefore use VPA without interference in relation to the HPA.
For a truly efficient scaling, the HPA and VPA complement
each other. HPA creates new replicas if the load raises. If the
space for these replicas is not sufficient, VPA will provide
some nodes, allowing HPA-made pods to run

can it use the same metrics? if we use metrics will both of it execute or do we need to define different metrics for both?

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to clarify one thing:

*If the space for these replicas is not sufficient, VPA will provide some nodes, allowing HPA-made pods to run*

If the number of nodes provided changes, it is horizontal scaling. Vertical scaling would mean changing the resource capacity of a node like number of cpus or amount of memory.

---

As for VPA working with HPA:

No, According to this [article](https://www.replex.io/blog/kubernetes-in-production-best-practices-for-cluster-autoscaler-hpa-and-vpa):

> #### Avoid using HPA and VPA in tandem
>
> HPA and VPA are currently incompatible and a best practice is to avoid
> using both together for the same set of pods. VPA can however be used
> with HPA that is configured to use either external or custom metrics.

AFAIK, k8s is better suited for HPA. K8s documentation also has HPA [page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/).

Comment: by this "however be used with HPA that is configured to use either external or custom metrics."  do you mean that other than memory/cpu metrics if hpa is scaled based on other metrics then we can use vpa and hpa together?

Comment: Even if you use different metrics as a trigger for change, the resource change might affect other metrics that are included in other auto-scaling system. It is possible but requires a lot of testing.